# Tiny Circular ProgressBar inside Edittext on the left side

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want to implement the tiny circular progress dialog inside the edittext on the left side and user can type the words after the progress dialog , How to implement this ?
I am new to android so i need your help.

Comment: you can only set any Image to left , right ,bottom or top of editText inside but for progress dialog you need take one LinearLayout with progress dialog in left and then add EditText .

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `RelativeLayout` with `EditText` and `ProgressBar` inside. Put the progress on the left side of layout and give some padding  left for the text inside `EditText`.

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingLeft="50dp"
      android:text="I'm EditText"
      />
  <ProgressBar
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:paddingBottom="8dp"
      />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]